# How to connect to a HTTP server using a proxy configuration with Swift 5 (why connectionProxyDictionary is being ignored)?

Tags: ios, swift, http, proxy, swift-playground

I need to connect to a webserver behind an HTTP proxy. I've tried using `URLSessionConfiguration` with `connectionProxyDictionary`, but it seems my proxy configurations are ignored because you can change the proxy host value to anything and the result is the same.

I have tried to use **Charles Proxy** to debug the situation in lieu of the proxy I need to connect to and found out that the request never reaches it, so I believe there is something wrong on my client-side code.

```
import Foundation

class URLSessionProxy: NSObject, URLSessionDelegate {

    func doRequest() {

        let configuration = URLSessionConfiguration.default
        configuration.connectionProxyDictionary = [
            kCFNetworkProxiesHTTPEnable: true,
            kCFNetworkProxiesHTTPProxy: "localhost",
            kCFNetworkProxiesHTTPPort: "8888",
        ]

        var request = URLRequest(url: URL(string: "https://ip.seeip.org/jsonip")!)
        request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Accept")

       URLSession(configuration: configuration, delegate: self, delegateQueue: OperationQueue.main)
        .dataTask(with: request, completionHandler: { (data, response, error) in
            if error == nil {
                print("url request = ", request.url?.absoluteString)
                print("headers request = ", request.allHTTPHeaderFields.debugDescription)
                print("response = ", response)
                print("data body = ", String(data: data!, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8.self))

            } else {
                print("error = ", error)
                print(error?.localizedDescription)
            }
        }).resume()
    }
}

URLSessionProxy().doRequest()
```

In the example given, I expect the connection to ip.seeip.org to happen indirectly, using the proxy I have set up on localhost:8888.​

gist: https://gist.github.com/brunabaudel/90a6873d2c3df6caeb89f8b7afc9adce

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The `kCFNetworkProxiesHTTP` keys only control the proxy that's used for `http` URLs. `https` URLs use a proxy defined with the `kCFNetworkProxiesHTTPS` keys.

Unfortunately the HTTPS keys aren't available on iOS (really not sure why), but the implementation is there, so you can just pass strings with the correct keys, which are `"HTTPSEnable"`, `"HTTPSProxy"`, and `"HTTPSPort"`.

Comment: Yes, you're alright. It works with HTTP only, but the keys for HTTPS are unavailable now (kCFNetworkProxiesHTTPSEnable, kCFNetworkProxiesHTTPSProxy, and kCFNetworkProxiesHTTPSPort).
Just to make it clear the proxy is HTTP, but I'm trying to reach an HTTPS server:
client (iOS application) <---> proxy (HTTP) <---> application server (HTTPS)

Comment: I just confirmed on macOS that the "HTTPS" keys apply when the URL being accessed is an https URL and the "HTTP" keys only apply when the target URL is an http URL. It's weird how the HTTPS constants aren't available on iOS. You could try passing the strings directly; it seems the string values are `"HTTPSEnable"`, `"HTTPSProxy"`, and `"HTTPSPort"`

Comment: Thank you a lot!! It worked like a charm. I don't know why Apple removed that keys. Maybe it's a security concern?
Also, do you mind to edit your main answer to I give you the score? I'm glad that it worked. Thank you again. :)

Comment: I'm not sure why but it doesn't work on iOS 13.5.1 for URLSessionWebSocketTask. I set up a basic WebSocket to wss://echo.websocket.org but the traffic doesn't appear on Proxyman or Charles too.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks very much. The following code works:

```
let configuration = URLSessionConfiguration.default
    let proxyConfiguration: [AnyHashable : Any] = [
        "HTTPSEnable": 1,
        "HTTPSProxy": "host.address",
        "HTTPSPort": 1234
    ]

    configuration.connectionProxyDictionary = proxyConfiguration
```